# Fatal error: Call to undefined function defined()

Tags: php

My php script had a weird error:Call to undefined function defined().

PHP codes below:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ERROR);
        break;
        case 'testing':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            break;
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
            break;
        default:
            exit('The application environment is not correct.');
    }
}
```

Has anyone seen this error.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd. `defined` is a built-in function.
Take a look at Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c and find out if this function is "occationally" commented.

Answer (score 0):

Your Script looks alright except you don't just do: `if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))`.... rather use only `switch(...)` or `if...elseif`.... This Snippet below mimics your Code but uses `defined()` differently (only during the Declaration of the Constant, like so:

```
    <?php
        // IMPLIES: 

        // IF THE CONSTANT 'ENVIRONMENT' IS NOT YET DEFINED ELSEWHERE,
        // DEFINE IT NOW AND GIVE IT A VALUE OF 'development'
        defined("ENVIRONMENT") or define("ENVIRONMENT", 'development');

        // NOW YOU CAN ENGAGE YOUR SWITCH CONSTRUCT LIKE SO:        
        switch(ENVIRONMENT){    //<== NOTICE: WE AIN'T USING ANY `IF`
                                //<== THIS COULD BE REPLACED WITH IF, IF YOU PREFER:
            case 'development':
                error_reporting(E_ERROR);
                break;
            case 'testing':
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                break;
            case 'production':
                error_reporting(0);
                break;
            default:
                exit('The application environment is not correct.');
        }
```